# create-react-app proxy broken after installing poetry on osx

Tags: macos, proxy, homebrew, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app with a backend application written on Python (using starlette, ariadne and uvicorn) on OSX.

The application was previously running using **pipenv**. After installing **poetry** through brew however (brew install poetry), it seems like CRA's proxy stopped working. I suspect this has something to do with homebrew but I have no idea what it is.

Here is my package.json config

```
{
  "name": "chat-ariadne-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "antd": "^4.18.9",
    "graphql": "^16.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^6.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.11.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm running the server using `poetry run uvicorn app`. However, I get the following error in the console:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /graphql from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

**Node version**
node -v
v17.6.0

**Operating System**

```
OS X Big Sur (version 11.5.2)
```

**Homebrew configuration**

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.4.1
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: ea0ddc3297739b7380887d4a7e6b6590c314dca9
Last commit: 2 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 49d411c9fe7e7cd2fba32e76ecbcd5a049556b73
Core tap last commit: 3 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 4
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.8/bin/ruby
CPU: quad-core 64-bit kabylake
Clang: 13.0.0 build 1300
Git: 2.23.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 11.5.2-x86_64
CLT: 13.2.0.0.1.1638488800
Xcode: N/A
```